# Does "maintaining" lead to "fostering?"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, writing

I'm writing a code of conduct for a small government department. It is going to be chock full of punchy, actionable phrases (no real complete sentences) that seek to convey an air of positivity.

Example:

> Maintain a positive attitude toward our work; foster this attitude department wide.

I feel that I understand what I am attempting to convey, but I am curious whether anyone else is reading this statement in the same way that I am. The department in question is having an issue with the negativity of a few individuals impacting the broader climate. My hope is to convey the idea that an individual's own attitude is part of a bigger picture—and not in a punitive way i.e., "Shape up or ship out."

**My main quandary, then**: do the verbs "maintain" and "foster" accomplish these goals of tone and meaning?

- Positivity
- A cause and effect relationship (individual attitude *affecting* everyone's work environment)
- Clarity of meaning
- Implying an action to be taken by the reader
- Is a semicolon appropriate here?

Any alternative word choices, rewrites, or reorganizations are welcome.

Comment: Question is unclear. Title asks "Is there an *implied relationship between* the verbs 'maintain' and 'foster?'" Whereas, the text asks for alternative words.

Comment: Look in a thesaurus for synonyms of 'foster'

Comment: What do you mean by "logical connection"? Question is still not clear. Surely you want to "foster [a positive] attitude department wide" irrespective of whether it is "maintained" in what ever area you refer to in your first clause. OTOH, maintaining it in your area does not "logically" mean that it is "foster[ed] department wide". You need to do both.

Comment: What I mean by "logical connection" is a cause and effect relationship: if a good attitude is "maintained," then it will be "fostered." Maybe the question is more one of scope than anything; a micro and macro relationship. I'm looking to imply that an individual's own attitude is a part of a larger picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful for your code of conduct to distinguish between what you expect the employees to do and the consequences of their doing this. So it seems reasonable to exhort employees to maintain positivity in their daily work and dealings with colleagues. If all do so, this will have the consequence of fostering a good atmosphere in the department.

I don't think you can expect the colleagues themselves to seek to directly foster this atmosphere. If anyone should do the fostering, it is the head of the department through measures that make her employees feel good about working there.

So unless you really expect the employees to do the fostering, you could just leave it at:

> Maintain a positive attitude towards work.

Answer (score 1):

You seem in your example to be exhorting people to both maintain a certain attitude, and foster that same attitude, whereas you would more likely conceive of it as foster *x* by doing *y* e.g. foster a harmonious environment, by maintaining good working relationships. Although there is an implied relationship between something maintained, and something fostered as a result, they're normally seen as two slightly different things.